# Constraint and Index Declaration in Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0

Tags: indexing, constraints, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I just want to clarify of what I read in the Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0 documentation. So, the provided way to configure index & unique constraint is just by defining it directly in the web console using Cypher query, and no more inside the application (like what @indexing tag does previously). Is it correct?

Thank you in advance and your response would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. Index maintenance and configuration is not the responsibility of the OGM or Spring Data. It can be configured as you said via the shell, or you can use the Session/Neo4jTemplate.execute with your Cypher statement.

Answer (score 1):

> Neo4j’s schema indexes are used automatically by Cypher when set up in your database. Spring Data Neo4j (version 4) does not provide facilities for handling that setup out of the box.

[its clearly mentioned in official  docs,](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_indexing)